# Cache Memory Vs Main Memory

Tags: architecture, memory, computer-architecture, caching

Why is the access time of the cache memory lesser than the access time of the main memory?

I have tried looking at the sites as - tutorialspoint.com, education-portal.com etc.

I know that the smaller the cache,the faster it is, but there must be some more explanantion to why cache memory is faster to access than main memory. 
 Please help.

Comment: Thank you. It helped but there are some terms I didn't understand but will study more. :)

Comment: The gist of it is that the technology used for cache memory is different (faster, more expensive, probably more power-hungry too) and the distance the data has to travel is much shorter. And in multi-core systems each core can usually write immediately to its own cache, but may have to synchronize with other cores working on the same memory contents before writing back to main memory.